# Debugging Windows CE 6 service

Tags: windows-services, windows-ce, visual-studio-debugging

**Update:** I've updated the text below to reflect results of my further investigations.

I want to debug my *Windows CE 6* service from *Visual C++ 2008*. But breakpoints in several service API functions don't get hit, while should be. And that's not all. Seems like **setting a breakpoint sometimes changes the code flow**.

I have breakpoints set on all the service's exported functions (*xxx_Init, xxx_Open, xxx_IOControl*, etc.). I deploy the service DLL debug binary to a device and then I attach the debugger to the *servicesd.exe* process on the device.

After I run

```
services load MYSVC
```

on the device console, the module gets loaded, all the breakpoints become enabled and then the breakpoint in the *xxx_Init* function gets hit. I then execute and exit the function by pressing F5 in VC++. So far, so good.

But then, I run the

```
services start xxx:
```

command. Under the hood it calls the *CreateFile* API which results in a call to my *xxx_Open* function. If the CreateFile succeeds, then the *DeviceIoControl* API is called, which in turn calls my *xxx_IOControl*.

My implementation of xxx_Open just logs and returns a non-zero value, allowing the upper CreateFile API call to succeed:

```
DWORD APIENTRY xxx_Open(DWORD data, DWORD access, DWORD shareMode)
{
    APP_LOG_INFO() << L"The service is being opened";
    return 1; // Breakpoint here
}
```

If there is a breakpoint set on the "return 1" line, the breakpoint does not get hit, but I've got the

```
xxx: is not a valid service
```

response on the console, as if the function returned 0. If I remove the breakpoint, then everything goes fine.

The same goes if I set a breakpoint on the code in xxx_IOControl function:

```
DWORD xxx_IOControl(DWORD code, /* ... */)
{
    DWORD error = ERROR_SUCCESS; // (1)
    switch (code) // (2)
    {
    ...
    default: // (3)
    ...
    }
```

Having a breakpoint on the line (1) leaves the error variable unitialized. Having a breakpoint on the line (2) makes the code to fall to the default branch on line (3), even if there exists a case branch for the code provided. In any of these cases the breakpoints are not hit.

At the same time, if I *LoadLibrary* my DLL (from a test executable), *GetProcAddress* of the xxx_Open and xxx_IOControl and call them, the debugger works as intended, all the breakpoints get hit and the code flow seem to be correct.

What am I missing? Why the debugger interfere with the services in such a weird way? Is there a way to reliably debug the service functions (I need *IOControl* mostly)?